# Silverlight WebConfig Error

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I try tp make a Silverlight project it is working in my local pc but when i publish the project to My ftp and after go to adress it is give a error like

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

```
Line 16:             <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
Line 17:         </httpModules>
Line 18:         <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"><assemblies><add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /></assemblies></compilation>
Line 19:     </system.web>
Line 20:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here for a solution: http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1772

Chances are the wrong .net framework has been selected in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Then you would need to make sure that the 4.0 Framework is installed on the server you FTPed your project to.